# How to extract string from response?

Tags: java

I already searched in Google about this matter. I just want to extract these strings `192.168.90.20`, `80`, `5225` and `96656` from this response.

The response is:

```
Ready 192.168.90.20:80 1.1
YID 5225 PID 96656
Connected
```

I used this code, but it didn't work.

```
public static final Pattern myPat1 = Pattern.compile("Ready (.+):(.+))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
public static final Pattern myPat2 = Pattern.compile("YID (.+) PID (.+))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher1 = myPat1.matcher(response);
Matcher matcher2 = myPat2.matcher(response);

if (matcher1.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}

if (matcher2.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher2.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: what did not work?

Comment: It didn't extract 192.168.90.20, 80, 5225 and 96656

Comment: "it didn't work" is pretty vague. Does your output always come in this format? Is the size of the number (length) always the same?

Comment: In general when you say it did not work then give some context. What is not working? have you some error messages or what is your output and what is your expected output

Comment: If it is because of your regex, try this out https://regex101.com/r/DrJfhF/1
this should match any of your given ip addresses with port.
Is this behind your port the version? the 1.1

Comment: Why do your regexes have a mismatched number of parentheses?

Comment: @ Stultuske Let's get to the heart of the matter without wasting time! My code didn't print the required output, If you're a professional programmer you will solve the problem! Good luck

Comment: @Alex, That's right! There is something wrong in my regex

Comment: @Dakar2021 I was getting to the "heart of the matter", that being you not providing enough context, and you hardly attempting to do anything yourself to solve your issue. SO is a place where we spend our own time helping you improve your code, not do your work for you.

Comment: `String[] numericalValuesArray = mystring.replaceAll("[^\\d+.: \n]", "").trim().split(":|\\s+|\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
String response = """
        Ready 192.168.90.20:80 1.1
        YID 5225 PID 96656
        Connected""";
System.out.println(response);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d.:]+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The output is:

```
Ready 192.168.90.20:80 1.1
YID 5225 PID 96656
Connected
192.168.90.20:80
1.1
5225
96656
```

The code uses [java text blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355).

Note that method `matches` tries to match the entire string, whereas method `find` searches for the next occurrence of the pattern in the string. Each time you call `find`, it starts searching from the end of the previous match.

Comment: wouldn't the regex also validate 102042.21421412.212.3232:900 as valid IP Address?

Comment: @Alex I just answered the question that was asked. Besides which, I see no mention of validating an IP address in the question.